# Flutter: TextField onChange function's conditional

Tags: flutter, dart

```
onChanged: (v) async {
  print(EmailValidator.validate(v));
  EmailValidator.validate(v)
      ? () async {
        print('email tureeee');
        }
      : () async {
          print('email not trueee');
        };
},
```

I have this conditional functions inside the `onChange()` of the TextField widget. `print(EmailValidator.validate(v));` seems to work. However, the conditional function does not execute when condition has been met.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the issue is here, you are creating another function. Since the `onChanged` calls when ever text changes. Now based on validation you are creating another anonymous function, which is need to be call to execute.
You can simply check the execution like

```dart
TextFormField(onChanged: (value) {
  value.isEmpty
      ? () async {
          print('email tureeee');
        }
      : () async {
          print('email not trueee');
        };
})
```

Now let say you like use this format executes the function. For this you can create and execute function like `(){...}()`

```dart
TextFormField(onChanged: (value) {
  value.isEmpty
      ? () async {
          print('email tureeee');
        }()
      : () async {
          print('email not trueee');
        }();
})
```

The same things go for `EmailValidator.validate(v)`. But instead of nesting like this, it would be better creating single `bool` and handle check operate to have clean code.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  onChanged: (v) async {
      print(EmailValidator.validate(v));
      if(EmailValidator.validate(v)){
        print('email tureeee');
      }else{
        print('email not trueee');
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

you're basically creating an anonymous function, which is never being called,
and it's quite unnecessary here

you can simply have if-else like shown below

plus `async` can be avoided, if you're not using `await` keyword inside `onChanged`

```dart
onChanged: (v) {
  final result = EmailValidator.validate(v);
  print(result);
  
  if (result) {
    print('email tureeee');
  } else {
    print('email not trueee');
  }
},
```